# Differential equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

How does one solve this differential equation?

$$y' = \frac{x^3 + 2x^2 y - y^3}{x^3 + x^2 y}$$

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: No effort shown, so I'm loathe to migrate to the [math site](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Oh well. If you try asking there again, be prepared to have at least shown what you tried, or at least your mathematical background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DSolve[y'[x] == (x^3 + 2 x^2 y[x] - y[x]^3)/(x^3 + x^2 y[x]), 
 y[x], x]
(* {{y[x] -> (x (-E^(2 C[1]) + x^2))/(E^(2 C[1]) + x^2)}} *)
```

or

$\left\{y(x)\to \frac{x \left(x^2-e^{2 c_1}\right)}{e^{2 c_1}+x^2}\right\}$

Where `C[1]` is a constant that depends upon initial conditions or other constraints.

Comment: Can you show me the steps how you came to this answer?

Comment: @MarkoDamnjanovic. There are no steps when _Mathematica_ software is used to solve the equation.